# ASP.NET, Visual Studio 2019, MySQL. The data provider 'Mysql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be found

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

When I try to set `SqlDataSource` I've got provider error. Server connection checked and it works

Editor image：

[image: Editor image]

Error message image：

[image: Error message image]

Problem is similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556708/the-data-provider-mysql-data-mysqlclient-could-not-be-found-in-the-system-conf) but recommended fix doesn't work and IDK what to do

Error picture from thread above

[image: thread_picture]

I've installed MySQL connector, MySQL for Visual Studio, but it doesn't help to me

UPD: [Here's a minimal project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JRdGNXDaqZptw08nhUyi4HOFft78kOcQ/view?usp=sharing) with an SQL DB (var_23.sql). In `Web.config` described a connecting to DB, the "Doctors" page has a `SqlDataSource` element, that do connection

Comment: After installing the connector and did you rebuild the project where you are trying to add data source?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a SqlDataSource anyways? That's a very outdated concept. Have you looked into the repository pattern for obtaining the data? You can combine that with an ObjectDataSource in Web Forms.

Comment: When asking questions in the stack overflow, please make sure your pictures and texts are in English, so that we can better understand your questions.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I've already added the same picture on English

Comment: @ValZubko Do you have time to check my answer?

Comment: I'll check it as soon as possible

Comment: @ValZubko Please add a [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the current information is not enough for us to solve your problem.

Comment: Please add the version numbers of your various programs and packages.

Comment: I've updated thread with an example

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, Please install `"Data storage and processing"` in visual studio installer.

[image]

If the corresponding package is missing during the compilation process, use `Alt+enter` to pop up a quick prompt to add it (you could also right-click `Reference`->`Manage Nuget Packages` to add the corresponding package)

Updated：

[image]

It turns out that I can run your program correctly, I downloaded a community version of mysql 8.0, and imported your database.

Because you create in Framework, I suggest you can remove `providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"`.

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: So, it doesn't help

Comment: @ValZubko I have updated my answer, please check it. If you have any question about it, please comment bellow.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't help

Comment: @ValZubko  Can you tell me, is there something wrong with my reproduce? I don't have the problem you describe. Is there anything missing. I just want to help you out. More detailed information can help me solve your problem.

Comment: I can't say that it's something wrong, because I just don't know what can be wrong. I'm trying to find a solution with another more cleaner VS version. Maybe it's a problem with a lot of installed libs or like that

Comment: @ValZubko ”I just don't know what could be wrong”? Isn't your problem not being able to connect to the database? I got it working correctly with the example you gave. So where is your problem and how can I reproduce it?

Comment: Hmm... did you connect to SqlDataSource via window (see editor image) ?